MSVC compiler bug with C++ generic lambda? (now with minimal repro)
(This is a follow-up to a question I posted a few hours ago, then deleted. I now have a minimal reproducible example in about 10 lines)
The following code will cause an access violation with MSVC, but works perfectly with gcc and clang.
#include <map>


template <typename T> auto inner = []()
//template <typename T> void inner()
{
    std::map<int, int> x;
    x.clear();  // Will cause an access violation
};

template <typename T> auto outer = []()
//template <typename T> void outer()
{
   inner<T>();
};



int main() 
{ 
    outer<int>();
}

See on compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/8j4b14hzn
If you uncomment the lines where I replace the generic lambdas with standard generic functions, everything works fine.
Am I doing something terribly wrong?
Edit: removed the shorter examples, which I reported too early.

Reproduced the access violation on my MSVC 2022 (C++20) in Debug with the first (longer) version. Looks like a MSVC bug. BTW - I couldn't reprodce with the second (shorter) version.

Old deleted question: MSVC Compiler bug? generic lambda fails, but its equivalent template function works

Crash when calling clear on an Empty Map and Segmentation fault calling std::map::clear

Both compiles without errors for me

@김선달 Note OP doesn't say that it doesn't compile but that they get access violation(which happens at runtime) in msvc.

@김선달 The problem isn't with compilation but execution.

You should report a bug.

I’m reporting it

I cannot reproduce in MSVC 2022 Version 17.9.2

@Fedor even with the first (longer) one ? I reproduced with it on MSVC 2022 17.2.5. So maybe they already fixed the bug.

MSVC2017, MSVC2019: no problems with the last, shortest example. You should update your version of MSVC to the latest patch.

@Wisblade: what about the longer examples. Do they work with your version?

None of those are generic lambdas.  Some of them are variable templates whose values are lambdas.

@PascalT. : doesn't crash either, but it isn't relevant - your problem is the same bug each time. The code should not crash, but it does: therefore, your compiler's version does something bad with stack-allocated containers, "clear" and var's lifetime - as the minimal example proves it - while mines don't. But my compilers are up-to-date, and yours probably isn't. Maybe you can try to debug inside STL to see what happens, or use dynamically allocated map to test it without stack storage, or add a "sleep" after "clear". But you have to update MSVC anyway.

@Wisblade: The shorter example were a mistake. Only the longer example does trigger the bug. I do have two versions of MSVC. One has the bug (17.4.0), and another which I just updated does not have it (17.9.6).

I reported the bug here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/std::map-access-violation-when-called-in/10647871?sort=newest
I cannot remove my post it so I edited it, by adding a mention that 17.9.6 does not trigger the bug.
However, I am worried that this might be used for exploits, since this is a quite common pattern.

Additional info: binaries produced with GitHub Runners as of Apr 26th 2024 using "windows-latest" images do suffer from this bug.

@PascalT. Thanks for the report. Just a little advice: beware of "nightly builds" or beta versions if you plan to use this code in production - that's... dangerous, at best. Prefer latest stable / release versions.

@Wisblade: "windows-latest" Github Runners are abolutely not beta. It just means you want to use the latest official toolset on windows.
